# hide div which not contain class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to switch div on hover on `li` element.

My li element looks like

```
<ul>
  <li id="id1" onmouseover="subDivision(this.id)">first line</li>
  <li id="id2" onmouseover="subDivision(this.id)">second line</li>
  <li id="id3" onmouseover="subDivision(this.id)">third line</li>
</ul>

<div class="submenu id1">
   First division
</div>
<div class="submenu id2">
   Second division
</div>
<div class="submenu id3">
   third division
</div>
```

jQuery code :

```
<script>
  $('.submenu').hide();
  function subDivision(divId) {
    $('.'+divId).show();
    $('.submenu not(.'+divId+')').hide();
  }
</script>
```

I want to show `div` with class as passed `id` and hide all `div` under `.submenu` div which does not contain passed `id`.

But this is not hiding `div` and showing all division after another without hiding previous one.

Comment: Use `:not()` instead `not()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addClass` & `removeClass` to show the `div` of concern on hovering `li`

```
function subDivision(divId) {
         $('.submenu').removeClass('showElem').addClass('hideElem');
          $('.'+divId).addClass('showElem');
    }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fdjsj6m8/)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should use unobtrusive JS to attach your event handlers instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes. From there you can use a simple selector to toggle the relevant element by its class. Try this:

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  $('.' + this.id).toggle();
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="id1">first line</li>
  <li id="id2">second line</li>
  <li id="id3">third line</li>
</ul>

<div class="submenu id1">
  First division
</div>
<div class="submenu id2">
  Second division
</div>
<div class="submenu id3">
  third division
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `:` in your pseudo-class selector although there is no need of space between them. If you added space it checks for descendants which don't have the class.

```
$('.submenu:not(.' + divId + ')').hide();
// --------^---------
```

---

The code can be even much more reducible

```js
$('li[id^=id]') //  get all li element where id start with id
.mouseover(function() { // bind mouseover event handler instead of inline
  $('.submenu.' + this.id) // get the element to show
  .show() // show the element
  .siblings('.submenu') // get all its siblings
  .hide(); // hide them
})
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="id1">first line</li>
  <li id="id2">second line</li>
  <li id="id3">third line</li>
</ul>

<div class="submenu id1">
  First division
</div>
<div class="submenu id2">
  Second division
</div>
<div class="submenu id3">
  third division
</div>
```